# React Native IOS Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I wrote an android project with react native and it works fine, but then I wanted to go with ios, I went to the ios folder and ran the pod install code, then I went back to the main folder and said yarn ios, but I am facing this error, what is the solution?

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 66. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening myappv2.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace myappv2.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myappv2 -destination id=600597F7-E729-4AB6-85FA-A68EBA352C05

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES


` 2022-06-16 15:28:05.261 xcodebuild[10727:218865] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-16 15:28:05.261 xcodebuild[10727:218865] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcodebuild: error: Scheme myappv2 is not currently configured for the build action.
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly;

```
# remove old CommandLineTools
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

# install latest
sudo xcode-select --install
```

**Do not forget to make these steps to initialize the path for Xcode**

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to preferences
3. Go to locations tab
4. Select an Xcode version in the select labeled "Command Line Tools"

React Native on the M1 chip is pain.... Good luck for it!

Comment: i will try in home bro

Comment: Not Working bro

Comment: You can try https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26118 answer. Deleting a few errors worked for me.

Comment: Any ideas if im working on windows?

Answer (score 0):

If Update is available then Just install Update and then Launch Xcode; it will ask you to install additional software. After installation finishes the errors will be solved.

Comment: if i softwareupdate --list, response No new software available.

Comment: This may be an answer for some. For those whose software is already up-to-date AND still receive this console output, it resolves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
rm Podfile.lock
pod install
```